# transformar Y-m-d H-i-s em d-m-Y H-i-s

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Como realizo a mudança de uma data que vem do banco de dados como `Y-m-d H-i-s (2018-04-24 16:07:17)` em  `d-m-Y H-i-s (24-04-2018 16:07:17)` no php? 
Tentei realizar esta operação com o comando date, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Use `date` em conjunto com a função `strtotime()`, assim `date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($dataVindaDoBanco));`

Comment: Funcionou man, obrigado!

Comment: @EvandroLacerda poderia publicar como resposta sua solução?

Comment: Publicado como resposta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date` em conjunto com a função `strtotime()`, assim `date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($dataVindaDoBanco));`

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar a classe `DateTime` do `PHP`, veja;

```
$date = new DateTime("2018-04-24 16:07:17");
print_r($date->format("d-m-Y H:i:s")); // saída: 24-04-2018 16:07:17
```

Você pode utilizar dinamicamente caso prefira;

```
$date = (new DateTime("2018-04-24 16:07:17"))->format("d-m-Y H:i:s")
```

Veja mais sobre a classe [`DateTime na documentação do PHP`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)